# Spanning tree with infinitely many chords.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

First, let me remind chord of graph.
An edge which joins two vertices of a cycle but is not itself an edge of cycle is chord of that cycle.

Now, I want to show that if a graph has spanning tree with infinitely many chords then all its spanning trees have infinitely many chords.

Comment: Consider an infinite ladder. Then one side, together with every rung is a spanning tree with infinitely many chords (each rung is a chord of a six cycle). But there is also a spanning tree consisting of the two sides plus one rung, and this has just one chord. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Casteels, If I understood correctly the second spanning tree, then   it has infinite many chord. You can add each rung and obtain a cycle.

Comment: The graph I mean is [Figure 1 on the second page here](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/D.Kuehn/tst.pdf). The rungs are the vertical edges, the sides are the sets of horizontal edges along the top and bottom respectively. The second spanning tree I meant consists of all horizontal edges and exactly one rung. This spanning tree has only one chord (the rung).

Comment: It is an exercise in Diestel's book. See page 252, exercise 7.

Comment: Indeed it is, and supposedly an easy exercise! He certainly wouldn't have missed such an easy counterexample, so I must be missing something. Maybe since that one rung is a chord of infinitely many cycles, it is counted infinitely many times? But I doubt the question would been phrased like it is if that was the intention.